# ionic 3 enable camera and mic access in WKWebView

Tags: cordova, ionic3, wkwebview, ionic-native, agora.io

i am working on ionic 3 webrtc project using agora javascript api..

working well in android

but in ios it shows error "enumerateDevices() not supported".

how to enable camera and mic access for WKWebView?

please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation. IOS does not completely support for any web view implementations other than safari browser. Even google chrome on safari can access the webrtc functionalities completely.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458